# which version mariadb can replace mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I know mariadb 5.3 can replace mysql5.3 with same functions.
Which version mariadb can replace mysql5.7 with same [JSON process functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html)?

Comment: that's not the same function! for example, has no JSON_APPEND()

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json_array_append/

Comment: I didn't suggest it was possible. I suggested that was the way to find out if it was possible!

Comment: different function, it means you need modify scripts when transfer database.what i ask is  SAME function

Comment: @jackson883 You're being a bit rude to someone who's attempting to help you out.

Answer (score 4):

MariaDB 10.2.4+ has all the same JSON functions as current MySQL 5.7. Additionally, MariaDB 10.2 provides functions [`JSON_VALUE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json_value/), [`JSON_QUERY`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json_query/), [`JSON_EXISTS`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json_exists/), [`JSON_COMPACT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json_compact/).

MariaDB does not have `JSON_APPEND`, and neither does MySQL 5.7. It was renamed to `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND` in MySQL 5.7.9, see [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-append).

MariaDB 10.2 does not have `column->path` and `column->>path` operators.

MariaDB 10.2 does not have JSON data type.

Functions which exist in both implementations don't necessarily behave identically, especially in cases when the standard does not define the outcome explicitly, and in error handling.

Some examples of differences:

- MariaDB does not remove duplicate keys as MySQL does (this dilemma
  was discussed at length in different sources, and currently it seems
  that the standard does not prohibit having duplicate keys, although
  discourages it);
- MariaDB does not re-order JSON keys/values like MySQL does;
- MariaDB often returns `NULL` and warnings when MySQL returns errors. It
  is done in order to stick to the standard where `NULL ON ERROR` is
  the default behavior. It is expected that `ON ERROR` clause will be
  eventually implemented.

Generally, MariaDB tries to be as close as possible to the subset of the standard that it implements.

Comment: which means transfer database need to verify php scripts?